# Efficient numerical solution of brownian motion SDE with non-smooth diffusivity

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to numerically solve the 1-dimensional stochastic differential equation for brownian motion (Fokker-Planck) with rapidly varying diffusivity $K$,

$$ \textrm{(Ito)}\quad dX_t = \frac{\partial K}{\partial X_t}dt + \sqrt{2K} dW_t.$$

As a toy example, consider $K = 2 + \sin(\lambda X_t)$ with a large $\lambda$. The regular Euler-Maruyama method fails in this case unless the time step is very small and I want to avoid that. I'm not very familiar with stochastic differential equations, but to me this smells like some kind of stiffness. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

In reality, the diffusivity $K$ is obtained by interpolating a high-resolution tabulated quantity. Both the derivative and antiderivative of $K$ are easily obtainable.

Comment: How small of a time-step are you trying to avoid? Have you tried Milstein or RK2? e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. RK2/Milstein does not work, unfortunately. Ideally, I would like timesteps that are 10-100 times larger than 1/(d2K/dx2).

Comment: Could you rewrite the right hand side like $$ \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\frac{\partial K}{\partial X_t} dt + \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\lambda}}dW_t ?$$ Then you can use homogenization techniques to get an approximation of $X_t$. Another thing you could do is run a discretisation of $X_t/\lambda$ instead of $X_t$ as the large drift could be causing problems, but you will still have the problem of having to resolve the rapid variations in $K$.

Comment: I don't quite follow you... What kind of substitution did you use to achieve the rewrite? Also I don't know what homogenization techniques you are referring to. Also I don't know if any of this helps at all.....

Comment: Apologies, I meant to ask if that rewrite would be possible; I pulled that expression from Pavliotis and Stuart's book Multiscale Methods. However, what I wrote above might actually be the wrong tack. Can we assume that $K$ is of the form $K = \tilde{K}\left(x/\varepsilon\right)$? Here $\varepsilon$ is the scale on which the diffusivity vary; think of it as $1/\lambda$ for your toy example. Then the generator of $X$ is given by $$ \mathcal{L}u = K \Delta u + \nabla K \cdot \nabla u = \text{div}\left(K \nabla u\right) =  \text{div}\left(\tilde{K} \left(x/\varepsilon\right)\nabla u\right) $$ ...

Comment: ...what happens to this partial differential operator as $\varepsilon \to 0$ is what's studied in homogenization, see [link](https://www.esaim-proc.org/articles/proc/pdf/2012/03/proc123701.pdf) for example for an intro. The limiting operator will often have an effective diffusivity, $K^*$, that is a kind of average of $\tilde{K}$. If I am correct if $\tilde{K}$ is periodic then $K^*$ may be explicitly computed, which should also give an effective SDE for whom you could use larger time steps as you will no longer have to resolve the rapid fluctuations in \(K\).

Comment: I think I understand. I was thinking of a solution along these lines, in my case the appropriate averaging operator is the harmonic average. Also, since this is 1-dimensional, advanced homogenization techniques are not necessary. It takes some computational effort to find the appropriate homogenization scale and perform the averaging, but it might be worth it in the end.